# Grab minimum time in year

Tags: excel, excel-formula

As an athlete I want to keep track of my progression in Excel.
I need a formula that looks for the fastest time ran in a given season. (The lowest value in E for a given year. For 2017, for example, this is 13.32, for 2018 12 and so on.
Can you help me further?
[image: Click here te view a screenshot of my Excel file]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of formula you can use `PIVOT` 
Keep the Year in `Report Filter` and Time into `Value`. Then on `value field setting` select `min` as `summarize value by`.

So every you change the year in the Filter the min value will show up.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
=AGGREGATE(15,6,E3:E6/(B3:B6=2017),1)
```

15 tell aggregate to sort the results in ascending order
6 tells aggregate to ignore any errors such as when you divide by 0
E3:E6 is your time range
B3:B6 is you Year as an integer.

B3:B6=2017 when true will be 1 and false will be 0 (provide it goes through a math operation like divide.

1 tells aggregate to return the 1st value in the sorted list of results